# How to get a table to adjust its size according to its container

Tags: html, css, html-table, resize

I'm trying have a table adjust its width and the width of its cells when the `div` it's contained it resizes. So when the frame width is reduced, the table width is reduced, keeping all cells equal-sized.

```
<div id="page">
    <table id="menubar">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <a href="somewhere1.html"><td class="menu">MenuItem1</td></a>
                <a href="somewhere2.html"><td class="menu">MenuItem2</td></a>
                <a href="somewhere3.html"><td class="menu">MenuItem3</td></a>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

My CSS looks like:

```
#page {
    background-color: #f0eae3;
    max-width: 960px;
    min-width: 450px;
    margin: auto;
}

.menu {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    width: 310px;
}
#menubar {
    width: 960px
}
```

It's probably really easy.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `#menubar`s `width` to `100%` to ensure the table takes up `100%` of the container `#page`. If you don't want the table to be bigger than `960px` you can set `max-width` to `960px` to stop it from expanding too far.

```css
#page {
    background-color: #f0eae3;
    max-width: 960px;
    min-width: 450px;
    margin: auto;
}
#menubar {
    max-width: 960px;
    width: 100%;
}
.menu {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 310px;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
    <table id="menubar">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <a href="somewhere1.html"><td class="menu">MenuItem1</td></a>
                <a href="somewhere2.html"><td class="menu">MenuItem2</td></a>
                <a href="somewhere3.html"><td class="menu">MenuItem3</td></a>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have so

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <a href=""><td>1</td></a>
    <a href=""><td>2</td></a>
    <a href=""><td>3</td></a>
    <a href=""><td>4</td></a>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It must be so

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="">1</a></td>
    <td><a href="">2</a></td>
    <td><a href="">3</a></td>
    <td><a href="">4</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/njhqfnut/

```css
#page {
    background-color: #f0eae3;
    max-width: 960px;
    min-width: 450px;
    margin: auto;
}

.menu {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    width: 310px;
}
#menubar {
    max-width: 960px
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
    <table id="menubar">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="menu"><a href="somewhere1.html">MenuItem1</a></td>
                <td class="menu"><a href="somewhere2.html">MenuItem2</a></td>
                <td class="menu"><a href="somewhere2.html">MenuItem3</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```